# Why are there no written lyrics for the songs from Barbudo's new album, The EP?

Tags: lyrics

I found a beautiful, psychedelic chill pop album known as The EP by Barbudo on Soundcloud. Their not very popular at all and the album was posted about a month or two ago.
 Their song Dog Daze especially caught my attention and I fell in love with it. I was also inspired to try and use a snippet of the song for a short pmv. I tried to find the lyrics for this song, seeing as how some words are lost in the music, and came up with no result what-so-ever. I was able to find their Facebook page, however they don't have any information on the matter.

Are there any written or published lyrics for Dog Daze by Barbudo? If not, why? Will there ever be?

Comment: You should ask them.

Comment: You are expecting that these artists officially say :"We don't published the lyrics for this reason ... "? Most of artists don't publish their lyrics, and if you can find their lyrics on the web, it is because fans wrote it. So if you can't find the lyrics of that song, it is because nobody did the job.

Comment: @Bebs, your comment could become an answer, because this is a type of question that is often asked

Comment: @Bebs I remember reading somewhere an explanation by Seal (of "Kiss From a Rose" fame) of why his albums lack lyric sheets: he thinks listeners' misheard lyrics make the songs more meaningful to each listener. I imagine the asker was expecting something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Although the songwriter owns the copyright of the song they may not own the publishing rights.

The [UK Guild Of Songwriters](https://www.songwriters-guild.co.uk/faq.htm), for example, offers this advice to aspiring artists:

> If you have a song which has been taken up by a record company or artiste then it may be advisable for you as the songwriter to retain the music publishing rights by forming a music publishing facility, therefore, retaining all the royalties 100%.

Clearly there will be a financial cost to establishing this and bands may opt instead to invest in producing the art, the EP in this case. Even contacting a reputable publisher will carry a cost:

> Music publishers take a percentage of the money being royalties that may be earned and these percentages are set out in the terms and conditions of the music publishing contract entered into with the songwriter, composer.

On occasion when some band become hugely successful, for example, Rolling Stones, Beatles, Zeppelin, Queen, then they create their own publishing companies so that they can exert greater freedom in publishing their work, including books of lyrics and score. These are, however, very much the exception.